# Why destructor cannot be template?

Tags: c++, templates, destructor, sfinae

I wan't to disable user declared *destructor* using **SFINAE** in union-like class as do it usual for *constructors* in classes:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>

template< typename A, typename B >
struct U
{
    constexpr U() = default;
    constexpr U(A _a) : a(_a), s{false} {}
    constexpr U(B _b) : b(_b), s{true}  {}

    union
    {
        A a;
        B b;
    };

    bool s;

    template< typename = std::enable_if_t< !(std::is_trivially_destructible< A >{} && std::is_trivially_destructible< B >{}) >, // disable if A and B is trivially destructible
              bool is_noexcept = (noexcept(std::declval< A >().~A()) && noexcept(std::declval< B >().~B())) > // disable if A or B is not destructible
    ~U() noexcept(is_noexcept)
    {
        if (s) {
            b.~B();
        } else {
            a.~A();
        }
    }  
};

int main()
{ 
    struct A {};
    struct B {};
    U< A, B > u;
    static_assert(std::is_literal_type< A >{});
    static_assert(std::is_literal_type< B >{}); // =>
    static_assert(std::is_literal_type< U< A, B > >{});
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but got an error:

```
main.cpp:24:5: error: destructor cannot be declared as a template
    ~U() noexcept(is_noexcept)
    ^
1 error generated.
Failure!
```

Is there theoretical reason for this restriction in C++? Or is it just a "legacy"?

Comment: @DavidHaim default constructor also can't get parameter, but it can be template.

Comment: Destructor has to be generated, default constructor don't (class may have other constructor).

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: What nobody mentioned yet: If the destructor is called automatically because some object goes out of scope, what template type should be used? ... Right. The same reason explains why it can't have normal function parameters.

Comment: @deviantfan Whole (imanginary destructor seclection inclusive) class template instantiated at point of construction. Scope is irrelevant.

Comment: @Orient I'm not sure if we understand each other. Every constructed object gets destructed again at some point of time, either by leaving some scope or by getting explicitely `delete`d if allocated with `new` (and some other stuff). No destructing possibility has a place to put templae types and parameters to.

Comment: Btw., about your noexcept, something is very wrong with it. While you're not actually throing, the conditional inclusion suggests you might, and that's wrong. A destructor is not allowed to throw exceptions.

Comment: You can call in your destructor some member function template - so your desired behavior is easy to achieve that way...

Comment: @deviantfan A destructor is allowed to throw exceptions.

Comment: @PiotrNycz I want to make the compiler to generate default implementation of destructor (or to leave it trivial) conditionally. I want to make my *container* (for `A` and `B`) class to be a literal type conditionally.

Comment: @Orient `A destructor is allowed to throw exceptions.` No it's not (partially wrong, partially UB). Please read the standard. Any destructor is automatically (implicitly) noexcept. And throwing out of a noexcept function usually terminates the program instead of triggering some `catch`

Comment: @deviantfan I think the assertion `Any destructor is automatically (implicitly) noexcept.` is definitely wrong. No UB there too. It is bad practice, not any more.

Comment: @Orient Why don't you search it in Google, instead of stating your opinion ("I think...")?

Comment: @deviantfan OK, I'll do instantly.

Comment: @deviantfan: Throwing exception inside destructor may produce cases where 2 active exceptions were simultaneous alive. It is that case which is UB.

Comment: @deviantfan You are right about implicit `noexcept`-ness.

Comment: This is also doable - just posted by Jarod42 - you can also check my version: http://ideone.com/OE987I

Answer (score 12):

Any class, `U`, can have one and only one destructor, which is declared within that class with the name `~U()` and accepts exactly no parameters.

A template function specifies a family of functions, where a "family" describes a set containing one or more, with no upper limit on the number of members.

The two concepts are mutually exclusive.   A class cannot simultaneously have exactly one destructor and a family of destructors.

Comment: Using SFINAE I can make "a family of functions" to provide the only viable function in general case.

Comment: I can't see contradiction: at first glance there are no insurmountable obstacles to introduce possibility of selection of destructors (or to make the compiler to provide default one conditionally).

Comment: That is because you don't understand the difference between a template definition and a template instantiation.   A template is a specification that permits multiple instantiations, depending on the parameters used.   If exactly one instantiation of a function is permitted, that function cannot be a template.   SFINAE only comes into play when a valid template is subsequently instantiated.   The error message you are seeing occurs when checking the template is valid.  If the template itself is invalid, the code will be rejected before any attempt to instantiate the template.

Comment: Last sentence make a big sense. Really so. Maybe having Concepts I'll obtain desired possibility.

Comment: Without knowing what the "desired possibility" is, I can only guess.  But I suspect what you probably need to do is have (partial) specialisations of your templated struct `U`.   Each specialisation of `U` will have its own destructor.   But the destructor itself will not be templated.

Comment: I want to make destructor defaulted conditionally.

Comment: Then you want to look at how you specialise struct `U` - since each specialisation is permitted only one destructor.

Answer (score 4):

As a work around, you may add layer and specialization, something like:

```
template <typename A, typename B,
          bool trivially_destructible = std::is_trivially_destructible<A>{}
                                    && std::is_trivially_destructible<B>{},
          bool is_no_except = noexcept(std::declval<A>().~A())
                        && noexcept(std::declval<B>().~B())>
struct UdestructorImpl;

template <typename A, typename B, bool is_no_except>
struct UdestructorImpl<A, B, true, is_no_except>
{
    ~UdestructorImpl() noexcept(is_no_except) = default;
}

template <typename A, typename B, bool is_no_except>
struct UdestructorImpl<A, B, false, is_no_except>
{
    ~UdestructorImpl() noexcept(is_no_except) = delete;
}

template< typename A, typename B > struct U : UdestructorImpl<A, B>
{
    // Implementation
};
```

Comment: Using EBO or this technique is straitforward, but too verbose.

Comment: Bases is the only choise for variadic class templates.